# Provide public specialization of protected template member function

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to do the following:

```
class Foo {
protected:
  template<Param>
  void operator()(const Param& param) {
     // stuff involving some RTTI magic
  }
public:
  void operator()(const A& param) should be operator()<A>;
  void operator()(const B& param) should be operator()<B>;
}
```

Basically, I have a generic operator() that takes a generic template parameter. But, I only want to publish specific specializations for type safety.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just give the private function a different name:

```
 class Foo
 {
 private:
     template <typename T> void foo(const T &);

 public:
     void operator()(const A & x) { foo(x); }
     void operator()(const B & x) { foo(x); }
 };
```

Comment: This was basically also my first idea, but is it possible to do it without an inline forward?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid the inline forward?

Comment: @user3612643: You probably have to explicitly instanciate `foo<A>` and `foo<B>` in that case.

Comment: I thought there's a more elegant way to publish a specialization.